# When I open Xml file in android studio, the android studio closed suddenly

Tags: android

When I open XML file in android studio, the android studio get closed suddenly.I am using android 3.3 and facing this problem without an error.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If this happens with particular file, please attach/post it within the question. Also, you could try to run Android Studio from command line and see if it outputs something when gets closed. Probably post this info as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the solution and possibilities for Android studio to crash:

1. Faulty Ram
2. Run Android Studio as Admin
3. Cleanup Caches
4. Reinstall the IDE (Don't import old settings)

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you!

delete caches folder from C: Drive.

C:\Users\admin.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches